# Polynomial, cubic roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> For which integers $a$ does
>   $$f(x) = x^3+(a-2)x^2+(4-2a)x-8$$
>   have three distinct integer roots? What are these values of $a$ and their respective roots?

So far I have factorised this with the remainder theorem and long division into $(x-2)(x^2+ax+4)$ but I'm not sure how to go from here onwards.

Comment: @achillehui It said integer roots, not real roots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having factored the polynomial, notice that 2 is an integer root. By Viète's formulas, the product of the other two roots – the roots of $x^2+ax+4$ – is 4. If all three roots are to be distinct integers, by factoring 4 we find only two possibilities: $(1,4)$ and $(-1,-4)$. $(2,2)$ and $(-2,-2)$ are excluded.

The polynomial with roots $(2,1,4)$ has $a=-5$; if a monic quadratic polynomial has roots $p$ and $q$, the first-degree coefficient is $-(p+q)$. Similarly, the polynomial with roots $(2,-1,-4)$ has $a=5$. So only $a=\pm5$ gives a polynomial with three distinct integer roots.